# Xamarin.Forms List view with simple primary text / detail text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The example on the Xamarin website doesn't have code that shows how to simple take a list of data objects and populate a ListView with TextCells with primary text and detail text.

My code looks like this:

```
var newsListings = await App.Api.News.GetNewsAsync(true);
                var simpleNews = new List<TextCell>();

                foreach (var newsData in newsListings.news)
                {
                    simpleNews.Add(new TextCell() { Text = $"{newsData.displayText}", TextColor = Color.SlateGray, Detail = $"{MonthHelper.GetShortMonth(newsData.displayDate.Month,'.')} {newsData.displayDate.Day}, {newsData.displayDate.Year}", DetailColor=Color.DarkGray });
                }

                NewsListing.ItemsSource = simpleNews;
```

Simple XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ListView x:Name="NewsListing"></ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

The output is a ListView that says Xamarin.Forms.TextCell 27 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind a list by creating an IEnumerable and assigning to it to ItemSource, and them by using a template to specify which properties from your data to display.

```
public class Data {
  public string Primary { get; set; }
  public string Secondary { get; set; }
}

// in your page's OnAppearing
listView.ItemsSource = new List<Data>() { // initialize your list // };

// XAML
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Primary}" DetailText="{Binding Secondary}">
        <DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why does this require me to create a new class just for binding when I should be able to have a list of TextCell's and just make that my source?

Comment: If you want to manually build a list of TextCells, use a TableView instead.  You don't have to create a new class, I just did that for the example.  If your "news" object is an IEnumberable you could just use that as your data source.